# What optimal selection statements are possible to select previous and next rows (in one statement)?

Tags: mysql, select

How to select previous **AND** next rows from an ordered table, ordered by an `order` column?

This is a simple example of such a table (e.g. `test_table`):

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| id     | name      | order    |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|    126 | Test 0    |        0 |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|     73 | Test 1    |        1 | >
+--------+-----------+----------+
|    801 | Test 5    |        5 | <<<
+--------+-----------+----------+
|      3 | Test 8    |        8 | >
+--------+-----------+----------+
|     45 | Test 12   |       12 |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

This is an example statement, that makes it possible to do what I need (*in this example I have the `order`-value 5, and I need the previous and next rows by `order`*):

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM test_table
        WHERE test_table.order < 5
        ORDER BY test_table.order DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS a

UNION

SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM test_table
        WHERE test_table.order > 5
        ORDER BY test_table.order LIMIT 1
    ) AS b
```

However, I think it is too complicated. Is there another way to do it, using less `selects` (and/or without a `union`)? In short: are there more performant/efficient and optimal statements/algorithms or some best practices?

---

To be clearer, I expect the following result set:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| id     | name      | order    |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|     73 | Test 1    |        1 |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|      3 | Test 8    |        8 |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

P.S. Please, do not use any procedures or custom functions. Assume that there are no appropriate administrator rights for it.

Comment: So do you always expect a 2 row result set?

Comment: No. 0, 1 or 2. Max. 2.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?  If using less than 8, then your current approach may be as good as you can do.

Comment: If there are no next AND no previous rows (if there is only one record) then I expect 0 results. If there are no next OR no previous rows, then I expect 1 value.

Comment: And what can you do in version 8?

Comment: There are lead and lag analytic functions available.

Comment: Wow. Ok. I didn't know about it. Cool.

Comment: I took a stab at a lead/lag answer, if you're interested.

Comment: IMHO your query is optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, your solution is already optimal. I would though write it a bit shorter and use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` (which is a shortcut for `UNION DISTINCT`):

```
(
    SELECT * FROM test_table
    WHERE test_table.order < 5
    ORDER BY test_table.order DESC LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT * FROM test_table
    WHERE test_table.order > 5
    ORDER BY test_table.order LIMIT 1
)
```

Given an index on the `order` column, it should also have the best possible performance.

Comment: That's indeed much better!

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way to do this would be to use the `LEAD` and `LAG` analytic functions:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT id,
        LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY `order`) id_lag,
        LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY `order`) id_lead
    FROM test_table
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte1 WHERE `order` = 5
)

SELECT id, name, `order` FROM test_table WHERE id = (SELECT id_lag FROM cte2)
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, `order` FROM test_table WHERE id = (SELECT id_lead FROM cte2);
```

Comment: This is not going to work. Window functions only operate on row sets filtered by the WHERE clause. With `WHERE order = 5` you have only one row in the set. Thus LEAD and LAG will be NULL.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Answered on a cell phone, hence not tested, but corrected now.